# Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'transactionManager' is required even after it is declared

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have already declared the transactionManager in my Config file as below.

```
@Bean
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    return new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory().getObject());
}
```

Even after the declaration, I see the error that Property 'transactionManager' is not found.

1. Trying to configure hibernate using Spring and Hibernate Contextual sessions.
2. Configured SessionFactory using LocalSessionFactoryBean.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! This question is a little short on information. Please take the [tour] and read [ask] to learn what we expect from questions. Also, try to provide a [mcve] that reproduces the above issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use interface instead of concrete class

```
@Bean
public TransactionManager transactionManager() {
    return new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory().getObject());
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but that did not help :(.

Comment: Got the issue resolved. Updated the version of hibernate to 4.x.y. By the way the above HibernateTransactionManager has the interface PlatformTransactionManager. Thank you.

Comment: @syashwanthk I answered from the phone, didn't check correct interface. Glad to know that the issue is resolved.